# How to use regexp in MATLAB to strictly match a substring and not a larger string containing that substring?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, substring

I would like to find whether a cell contains the substring `foo` and only this string (nothing before, nothing after) in a series of cells that may contain `foobar`.

I am currently using `regexp` in `MATLAB` and would like to tweak the searched pattern `regexp` to exclude cells that contain a string that contains the substring I defined.

I know it kind of goes against the very idea of `regexp`, but I am fairly certain there is a way to do what I want.

As a MWE, here is a snippet of the data I have (in cell format), called `potentialfields`:

```
'horaracha'
'sol'
'presmax'
'horapresmax'
'presmin'
'horapresmin'
```

and the `regexp` expression that I am currently using:

```
selected_fields={'sol','presmin'};
diffset=setdiff(potentialfields,selected_fields);
pattern=strjoin(diffset,'|');
idx_to_delete=~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(potentialfields,pattern));
```

The expected output of `idx_to_delete` is the following:

```
1 0 1 1 0 1
```

At the moment, the output is `1 0 1 1 1 1` because `horapresmin` contains `presmin`.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Use word boundaries, `\<` and `\>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for your answer. It is indeed in that way. However, a little tweak was needed. Here is the correct expression, which you can post as answer and I will accept it:
  pattern=strjoin(diffset,'\\>|\\<');
    pattern=strcat('\<',pattern,'\>');
    idx_to_delete=~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(potentialfields,pattern));

The word boundaries needed to be escaped by '\' and the strcat takes care of the start and end of the chain of characters.

Comment: Isn't `pattern = strcat('\\<(', strjoin(diffset,'|'), ')\\>')` enough? I added grouping so that you do not have to multiplicate word boundaries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. The second option does not work.

Comment: Is it because of backslashes? The idea is correct, the pattern should look like `\<(abc|def)\>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regexp` is overkill here, `ismember` is an in-built function specifically designed for finding exact strings in a cell

```
idx_to_delete = ismember( potentialfields, selected_fields );
```

If you're really set on `regexp` you can use the start anchor (`^`) and end anchor (`$`) like so:

```
pattern = ['^(', strjoin( selected_fields, '|' ), ')$'];
idx_to_delete2 = ~cellfun( @isempty, regexp( potentialfields, pattern ) );
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Seeing this now, I don't know why I bothered with `regexp`.

Comment: @user89073 sometimes it takes asking a bunch of random people on the internet to be able to see the wood for the trees :)

Comment: :) yes, and the worst part is that I have been working with MATLAB for some years, but somehow I saw an answer on Matlab Central, tried to apply it without realizing that there was an easier route. I guess I got tricked by the `@cellfun` part and tried to keep it at all costs. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the word boundary based regex dynamically:

```matlab
pattern = strcat('\<(', strjoin(diffset,'|'), ')\>')
idx_to_delete=~cellfun(@isempty,regexp(potentialfields,pattern))
```

With `strjoin(diffset,'|')`, you get the alternation pattern created, and the `\<(...)\>` is a grouping construct wrapped with word boundaries to only match whole words where word boundaries apply to every alternative start and end char.